# How do I increment just one number in a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I increment just one number in a formula?

Here is my formula

```
=LOOKUP(C1-1,B3:B365,D3:D365).
```

I want to drag the formula along the row so that just the one number increases by one increment for each cell accross.

So the next cell would read

```
=LOOKUP(C1-2,B3:B365,D3:D365).
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little abuse that will do what you need:

```
=LOOKUP($C$1-ROW(1:1),$B$3:$B$365,$D$3:$D$365)
```

assuming you are dragging down.

If you would drag to the right, you would have to substitute `ROW(1:1)` by `COLUMN(A:A)`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix rows like this:

```
...,B$3:B$365,D$3:D$365
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all you help guys, but the formula requirements changed, but I managed to find out how to do what I needed to do in the end.

I used another cell reference form the row above the formula to increment the part of the formula that required it.

I needed to develop it further though so that the #N/A's were ignored.

The formula eneded up as:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP($C$1-B371,$B$3:$B$365,$D$3:$D$365),"")
```

Thanks for all your suggestions though. I find these support communities veru useful and will use them a lot more often in the future.